# Nested Post Model Link broken on static_page in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hyperlink, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

Alright I have a application where users can create collections and once they create a collection they can create products to that collection. So each collection has many products and each product belongs to a collection. On the Collections view and on the Products view the links work great. For clarifying the products are getting associated through a collection_id that is tied to them to tell them which collection they belong to. My usual method which works for the products controller and collections controller is this

```
def show
  @collection = Collection.find(params[:collection_id])
  @design = @collection.designs.all
end
```

The problem I'm having is on a static page...lets call it the home page. On this page I'm listing ALL of the products. if you click on a product it takes you to the corresponding product page (through the collections ie localhost/collections/2/products/5....those numbers relate to the id's of the collections and products).

I'm using the same links I use in the Collection and Product views which is

```
link_to collection_design_path(@collection, design)
```

Like I mentioned these links work great for the collection and product views. Here is my static_pages_controller for the home page

```
def home
  @design = Design.all
end
```

It shows all of the designs but the links look like this

```
localhost/collections//designs/3
```

It's skipping over the collection's id. Does anyone have a solution to this? I've asked this question before but the answers were all incorrect unfortunately.

**EDIT**

Designs and Products are the same thing. I scaffolded with the name designs so im using that but they are basically products...in case that confuses anyone reading

**EDIT**
Here is the routes file

```
resources :collections do
  resources :designs do
    member do
      post :like
      post :unlike
    end
  end
end
```

you can ignore the like and unlike..thats just for liking and unliking products/designs..the routes file shows you how the designs are nested in the collection link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you iterate over your `@design` collection:

```
<ul>
  <% @design.each do |design| %>
    <li><%= link_to collection_design_path(design.collection, design) %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: veritas1, you just made my weekend

Answer (score 0):

Your routes are perfect. Most likely your `@collection` has an nil ID, because was not saved yet.

You can also try

```
<%= link_to "link" [@collection, design] %>
```

Comment: I wish it were that easy! The designs and collections have the id associated to them! Like i was saying it if I'm showing all of the designs/products in the design/index page it works fine, because the design/index is showing all of the designs/products associated to the specific collection. As soon as i show all of the designs, regardless of collection, the links break

Comment: Yep I just checked the console and all the designs have the appropriate collection_id associated to it and all the collections have the right id's as well...I think its something to do in the controller or the link_to

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jhjguxin/3074080/fa5d8f6041f0e456c58ab11600d307979cd35874#file-creating-nested-resources-in-ruby-on-rails-3-and-updating-scaffolding-links-and-redirection-markdownI found this today and it mirrors mine identically. It just doesn't show you how to list all of the Children items on a totally different view (like a home page)

Comment: Because the typical way to show all of the children items is showing all of the childrens items associated to  a certain parent item. In my case it's just showing ALL of the children (which is what i want) it's just breaking the links